# Receiver is not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have two implementation receiver.

**First implementation:**

```
    public class ApplicationStartListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
        Context mContext;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                mContext = context;
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "FUI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.v("Server application FUI", intent.getAction());
        }
```

This implementation is not working.

**Secong implementation:**

```
    public class TestActiv extends Activity{

        public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
            intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
            intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED);
            intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
            intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);



            BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Log.v("Server applic", "FUI: " + intent.getAction());
                }
            };
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
        }
    }
```

Why is not work first implementation BroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 0):

To register this receiver this cannot be inside the AndroidManifest.xml, register at runtime

Register this receiver in any service.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: My project no have activity or service. Register receiver must be static.

Comment: @user1854307 Create a service and  Write this code in service and start the service. Surely It will help I had same problem earlier. I solved this like this.

Comment: I need to receiver register in AndroidManifest.xml. I did but this implementation no working.

Comment: <receiver android:name=".ApplicationStartListener">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: @user1854307 It will not work I assure you. You need to create a service for this.

Comment: Why such implementation will no work? Documentation offers such variation. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: First, unlike other broad casted intents, for Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON you CANNOT declare them in your Android Manifest! I’m not sure exactly why, but they must be registered in an IntentFilter in your JAVA code.

Comment: Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON i used for example. In project i must Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED. It can be register in manifest?

Comment: @user1854307 I think you was registering the this receiver in manifest.xml. You are now registering it at run time. I think your previous problem has been solved. let me know if not solved and remove all intent except screen on and off.

Comment: @user1854307 Why you changed this question completely. You started from broadcast receiver for screen on and off was not register from androidmanifest.xml and now Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED. This is wrong you should not change the complete question.

Comment: @user1854307 I shared the solution for your earlier problem and after editing the question you posted your new answer of new problem.

Comment: ACTION_SCREEN_ON this example for training. This intent works, others not working. My question was not working static registration receiver.

Comment: @user1854307 Initially you post this question. You edited the question in smart way. Anyways..

Comment: Why the receiver not working with static registration? Question was so.

Comment: @user1854307 I told you and give alternative "First, unlike other broad casted intents, for Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON you CANNOT declare them in your Android Manifest! I’m not sure exactly why, but they must be registered in an IntentFilter in your JAVA code."

Comment: @user1854307 I told in above comment to you you must be registered in an IntentFilter in your JAVA code

Comment: I get it. Your comments apply to all intent?

Comment: @user1854307 so what solution you find to register this receiver static in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Intent SCREEN_ON and SCREEN_OFF i do not need. Need only PACKAGE_CHANGED. It works when running applications on the device?

```
    public class TestActiv extends Activity{

        public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);  


            BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Log.v("Server applic", "FUI: " + intent.getAction());
                }
            };
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
        }
    }
```